# App pool crash : IIS Express vs Local/Server IIS

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, application-pool

I have improved some external dll in a web API application. If I run it using Visual Studio's IIS Express then it works fine. But if I depoy it to local or server IIS then App is crashing the App pool. Is there any way to find the problem?

Application is crashing, when I call constructor of external dll.

Comment: Look in the server's application logs. It will give you a clue, if you're unsure still you can always add it here.

Comment: Application log is showing warning User Profile Service. Event Id: 1530. Description: Windows detected your registry file is still in use by other application or service. The file will unload now. The application or service that hold your registry file may not function properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed app pool settings on local/server IIS.

Open IIS - Application Pools - select your application's app pool - advanced settings

Set

Identity : LocalSystem

Rapid-Fail Protection - Enabled : False

I don't know how but it fixed my issue.

Comment: This is kind of a 'sweeping under the carpet' approach - rapid fail protection will stop the App Pool after _x_ failures in a short time period. Your underlying problem will still be occurring so it would be best to Debug your way through the User problems. Perhaps the AppPool Identity cannot login.

Comment: Thanks @G0dsquad. How to fix the issue? I cannot debut the application because it is crashing the app pool.

Comment: Did you figure out how to debug?